# How to delete one of two users with the same name?

Tags: users

While trying to install Hadoop I created two users, one with the same name than the usual user. I want to get rid of it without deleting the one I'm usually using. Do you know how to do it ?

Here is the `gedit /etc/passwd` output :

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/usr/sbin/nologin
bin:x:2:2:bin:/bin:/usr/sbin/nologin
sys:x:3:3:sys:/dev:/usr/sbin/nologin
sync:x:4:65534:sync:/bin:/bin/sync
games:x:5:60:games:/usr/games:/usr/sbin/nologin
man:x:6:12:man:/var/cache/man:/usr/sbin/nologin
lp:x:7:7:lp:/var/spool/lpd:/usr/sbin/nologin
mail:x:8:8:mail:/var/mail:/usr/sbin/nologin
news:x:9:9:news:/var/spool/news:/usr/sbin/nologin
uucp:x:10:10:uucp:/var/spool/uucp:/usr/sbin/nologin
proxy:x:13:13:proxy:/bin:/usr/sbin/nologin
www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/usr/sbin/nologin
backup:x:34:34:backup:/var/backups:/usr/sbin/nologin
list:x:38:38:Mailing List Manager:/var/list:/usr/sbin/nologin
irc:x:39:39:ircd:/var/run/ircd:/usr/sbin/nologin
gnats:x:41:41:Gnats Bug-Reporting System (admin):/var/lib/gnats:/usr/sbin/nologin
nobody:x:65534:65534:nobody:/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
systemd-timesync:x:100:102:systemd Time Synchronization,,,:/run/systemd:/bin/false
systemd-network:x:101:103:systemd Network Management,,,:/run/systemd/netif:/bin/false
systemd-resolve:x:102:104:systemd Resolver,,,:/run/systemd/resolve:/bin/false
systemd-bus-proxy:x:103:105:systemd Bus Proxy,,,:/run/systemd:/bin/false
syslog:x:104:108::/home/syslog:/bin/false
_apt:x:105:65534::/nonexistent:/bin/false
messagebus:x:106:110::/var/run/dbus:/bin/false
uuidd:x:107:111::/run/uuidd:/bin/false
lightdm:x:108:114:Light Display Manager:/var/lib/lightdm:/bin/false
whoopsie:x:109:117::/nonexistent:/bin/false
avahi-autoipd:x:110:119:Avahi autoip daemon,,,:/var/lib/avahi-autoipd:/bin/false
avahi:x:111:120:Avahi mDNS daemon,,,:/var/run/avahi-daemon:/bin/false
dnsmasq:x:112:65534:dnsmasq,,,:/var/lib/misc:/bin/false
colord:x:113:123:colord colour management daemon,,,:/var/lib/colord:/bin/false
speech-dispatcher:x:114:29:Speech Dispatcher,,,:/var/run/speech-dispatcher:/bin/false
hplip:x:115:7:HPLIP system user,,,:/var/run/hplip:/bin/false
kernoops:x:116:65534:Kernel Oops Tracking Daemon,,,:/:/bin/false
pulse:x:117:124:PulseAudio daemon,,,:/var/run/pulse:/bin/false
rtkit:x:118:126:RealtimeKit,,,:/proc:/bin/false
saned:x:119:127::/var/lib/saned:/bin/false
usbmux:x:120:46:usbmux daemon,,,:/var/lib/usbmux:/bin/false
mike:x:1000:1000:mike,,,:/home/mike:/bin/bash
mongodb:x:121:65534::/home/mongodb:/bin/false
hadoop:x:1001:1001::/home/hadoop:
sshd:x:122:65534::/var/run/sshd:/usr/sbin/nologin
hduser:x:1002:1001:mike,A10,+33620050318,:/home/hduser:/bin/bash
```

I'm using `ubuntu 16.04`

Comment: What tool let you create a duplicate username?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams `sudo addgroup` or `sudo adduser`. I don't remeber if it is from from [this tutorial from michael-noll](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/)

Comment: "or"? As in you don't know which one?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, Indeed, I noticed it while restarting my laptop

Comment: I don't think either of those commands will let you create a redundant/duplicate user. What makes you think you have two users with the same name?

Comment: @igal When I log into my computer I have `mike` twice and `hadoop`plus `Guest session`. When I want to switch account I can log into `mike` or `mike` and the two others. I would love to give a screenshot but I can't as far as the switch session bar disappear while taking it

Comment: You should update your question to include your OS and probably also the content of your `/etc/passwd` file. Are there two "mike" users listed in `/etc/passwd`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the following two lines taken from your `/etc/passwd` file:

```
mike:x:1000:1000:mike,,,:/home/mike:/bin/bash
hduser:x:1002:1001:mike,A10,+33620050318,:/home/hduser:/bin/bash
```

You have two different users with different login names, but with the same "Full Name" of "mike". My guess is that your "duplicate" user is the one with login name "hduser".

For more information about the format of the `/etc/passwd` file you might refer to the following page from the Linux Documentation Project:

- [Linux Administration Made Easy - Section 6.6: Linux Password & Shadow File Formats](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lame/LAME/linux-admin-made-easy/shadow-file-formats.html)

I would also assume that the "Full Name" (i.e. "mike") is what's being displayed by your GUI login screen. If so, then that's the user you should delete. You can do this from the command-line like so:

```bsh
sudo userdel hduser
```

You could also do this via the Ubuntu GUI. For further discussion regarding user management in Ubuntu you may refer to the following post on AskUbuntu:

- [How to manage users and groups?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66718/how-to-manage-users-and-groups)